# Promoting nested columns of dataframes

Tags: r

I have this list of 2 dataframes. I want to rbind the dataframes together to form one dataframe.

```
dat <- list(structure(list(mbid = c("eda07157-11a6-4ab0-b9e1-faca2fde9bf3", 
"c8d8485f-cc09-402b-8ca1-4aeed9a88285", "76be87f4-ce0b-4715-baa8-f83c9627e5b2", 
"09c1a6a6-b77d-4f67-886d-bddd800aa4f8", "6a88e9e5-12a8-44ca-932a-1c0146d5f944", 
"218543bf-e7ce-4c30-9ee6-25cf6b3cd36a", "be0f5e41-7f98-484f-af05-2830e042bbee", 
"00a2c84a-782d-49c3-ac44-b00bf597b241", "833fc2d8-7ff6-45aa-af5f-3ad66f57fe8d", 
"76be87f4-ce0b-4715-baa8-f83c9627e5b2", "56c3c709-ccd7-45fc-9d7e-74b80fb2a21d", 
"76be87f4-ce0b-4715-baa8-f83c9627e5b2", "76be87f4-ce0b-4715-baa8-f83c9627e5b2", 
"76be87f4-ce0b-4715-baa8-f83c9627e5b2", "76be87f4-ce0b-4715-baa8-f83c9627e5b2", 
"c8d8485f-cc09-402b-8ca1-4aeed9a88285", "76be87f4-ce0b-4715-baa8-f83c9627e5b2", 
"d9d3490e-ed30-40a9-adfe-875f7d2ee5dc", "062f9a95-3b40-44f3-8438-65d476f35adb", 
"208621bb-9950-4207-a9c5-d299d4a54134"), name = c("Better At My Worst", 
"Top Rolled Down", "Lifelines & Superheroes", "Same Kind", "Heart Breaks", 
"Going Under (Didn't Have To)", "Blood Is Thicker Than Water", 
"Forever Begins Tonight", "Who Said It", "Lifelines & Superheroes", 
"Lay Some Love", "Lifelines & Superheroes", "Lifelines & Superheroes", 
"Lifelines & Superheroes", "Lifelines & Superheroes", "Top Rolled Down", 
"Lifelines & Superheroes", "Endless", "Nothing Good Comes Easy", 
"House"), date = structure(list(uts = c("1550752371", "1550752184", 
"1550751935", "1550751823", "1550751613", "1550751401", "1550751196", 
"1550750921", "1550750697", "1550750478", "1550750320", "1550750071", 
"1550749825", "1550749440", "1550749119", "1550748939", "1550748721", 
"1550748477", "1550748220", "1550748020"), `#text` = c("21 Feb 2019, 12:32", 
"21 Feb 2019, 12:29", "21 Feb 2019, 12:25", "21 Feb 2019, 12:23", 
"21 Feb 2019, 12:20", "21 Feb 2019, 12:16", "21 Feb 2019, 12:13", 
"21 Feb 2019, 12:08", "21 Feb 2019, 12:04", "21 Feb 2019, 12:01", 
"21 Feb 2019, 11:58", "21 Feb 2019, 11:54", "21 Feb 2019, 11:50", 
"21 Feb 2019, 11:44", "21 Feb 2019, 11:38", "21 Feb 2019, 11:35", 
"21 Feb 2019, 11:32", "21 Feb 2019, 11:27", "21 Feb 2019, 11:23", 
"21 Feb 2019, 11:20")), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame"), 
    artist = structure(list(mbid = c("6a87448d-a1bc-4e8a-8c4d-b7366662cc71", 
    "6a87448d-a1bc-4e8a-8c4d-b7366662cc71", "6a87448d-a1bc-4e8a-8c4d-b7366662cc71", 
    "6a87448d-a1bc-4e8a-8c4d-b7366662cc71", "6a87448d-a1bc-4e8a-8c4d-b7366662cc71", 
    "6a87448d-a1bc-4e8a-8c4d-b7366662cc71", "6a87448d-a1bc-4e8a-8c4d-b7366662cc71", 
    "6a87448d-a1bc-4e8a-8c4d-b7366662cc71", "6a87448d-a1bc-4e8a-8c4d-b7366662cc71", 
    "6a87448d-a1bc-4e8a-8c4d-b7366662cc71", "6a87448d-a1bc-4e8a-8c4d-b7366662cc71", 
    "6a87448d-a1bc-4e8a-8c4d-b7366662cc71", "6a87448d-a1bc-4e8a-8c4d-b7366662cc71", 
    "6a87448d-a1bc-4e8a-8c4d-b7366662cc71", "6a87448d-a1bc-4e8a-8c4d-b7366662cc71", 
    "6a87448d-a1bc-4e8a-8c4d-b7366662cc71", "6a87448d-a1bc-4e8a-8c4d-b7366662cc71", 
    "6a87448d-a1bc-4e8a-8c4d-b7366662cc71", "6a87448d-a1bc-4e8a-8c4d-b7366662cc71", 
    "6a87448d-a1bc-4e8a-8c4d-b7366662cc71"), `#text` = c("The McClymonts", 
    "The McClymonts", "The McClymonts", "The McClymonts", "The McClymonts", 
    "The McClymonts", "The McClymonts", "The McClymonts", "The McClymonts", 
    "The McClymonts", "The McClymonts", "The McClymonts", "The McClymonts", 
    "The McClymonts", "The McClymonts", "The McClymonts", "The McClymonts", 
    "The McClymonts", "The McClymonts", "The McClymonts")), row.names = c(NA, 
    20L), class = "data.frame"), album = structure(list(mbid = c("7bd6329b-b702-45f9-8420-be486dc1bd6d", 
    "7bd6329b-b702-45f9-8420-be486dc1bd6d", "7bd6329b-b702-45f9-8420-be486dc1bd6d", 
    "7bd6329b-b702-45f9-8420-be486dc1bd6d", "7bd6329b-b702-45f9-8420-be486dc1bd6d", 
    "7bd6329b-b702-45f9-8420-be486dc1bd6d", "7bd6329b-b702-45f9-8420-be486dc1bd6d", 
    "7bd6329b-b702-45f9-8420-be486dc1bd6d", "7bd6329b-b702-45f9-8420-be486dc1bd6d", 
    "7bd6329b-b702-45f9-8420-be486dc1bd6d", "7bd6329b-b702-45f9-8420-be486dc1bd6d", 
    "7bd6329b-b702-45f9-8420-be486dc1bd6d", "7bd6329b-b702-45f9-8420-be486dc1bd6d", 
    "7bd6329b-b702-45f9-8420-be486dc1bd6d", "7bd6329b-b702-45f9-8420-be486dc1bd6d", 
    "7bd6329b-b702-45f9-8420-be486dc1bd6d", "7bd6329b-b702-45f9-8420-be486dc1bd6d", 
    "14e7511a-4a43-4225-8403-312d9b19c2dc", "14e7511a-4a43-4225-8403-312d9b19c2dc", 
    "14e7511a-4a43-4225-8403-312d9b19c2dc"), `#text` = c("Here's To You & I", 
    "Here's To You & I", "Here's To You & I", "Here's To You & I", 
    "Here's To You & I", "Here's To You & I", "Here's To You & I", 
    "Here's To You & I", "Here's To You & I", "Here's To You & I", 
    "Here's To You & I", "Here's To You & I", "Here's To You & I", 
    "Here's To You & I", "Here's To You & I", "Here's To You & I", 
    "Here's To You & I", "Endless", "Endless", "Endless")), row.names = c(NA, 
    20L), class = "data.frame")), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(mbid = c("87dc9c1c-9cf0-38ad-a5e7-1e8005114e27", 
    "", "655b38ca-e847-3134-8da0-b4603349456c", "", "1782eb15-be64-4a7f-878b-e3c29fb0bd1c", 
    "1bc6476a-5545-3af6-aabf-dc812b498587", "10362cc6-40dd-30d3-a2da-7f753a0f3de4", 
    "620d1ddd-486a-3928-acb2-ec1625b4a929", "079a121e-3950-45d9-9a68-f10301241708", 
    "48a7c35a-6558-4e58-a72b-3044cea36564", "69d485ce-d6e7-3976-be8b-751b5a5067b7", 
    "1541af02-b377-42a7-813a-6a5a5576d61a", "156502d5-58c7-3c68-93be-c08eeab64974", 
    "538f206f-d5e4-3d23-8671-85b61d46b96e", "538f206f-d5e4-3d23-8671-85b61d46b96e", 
    "156502d5-58c7-3c68-93be-c08eeab64974", "1782eb15-be64-4a7f-878b-e3c29fb0bd1c", 
    "156502d5-58c7-3c68-93be-c08eeab64974", "0089b844-3367-4dae-ad24-16ffc41919a8", 
    "0089b844-3367-4dae-ad24-16ffc41919a8"), name = c("Wish I Could", 
    "Her e æ (Hei, her er jeg)", "Det fine vi hadd' sammen", 
    "When the Stars Go Blue (feat. Bono) - Live in Dublin", "You Weren't There", 
    "You Will Cry No More", "Do You Remember", "Here We Are", 
    "What If", "Hope You're Happy", "All I Can Say", "How Would It Be", 
    "Another Day", "Disguise", "Disguise", "Another Day", "You Weren't There", 
    "Another Day", "No Surrender", "No Surrender"), date = structure(list(
        uts = c("1548015363", "1548015090", "1548014829", "1548014569", 
        "1548014357", "1548014131", "1548013925", "1548013721", 
        "1548013487", "1548013182", "1548012905", "1548012667", 
        "1548000979", "1548000979", "1547992991", "1547992735", 
        "1547984975", "1547984727", "1547984379", "1547984126"
        ), `#text` = c("20 Jan 2019, 20:16", "20 Jan 2019, 20:11", 
        "20 Jan 2019, 20:07", "20 Jan 2019, 20:02", "20 Jan 2019, 19:59", 
        "20 Jan 2019, 19:55", "20 Jan 2019, 19:52", "20 Jan 2019, 19:48", 
        "20 Jan 2019, 19:44", "20 Jan 2019, 19:39", "20 Jan 2019, 19:35", 
        "20 Jan 2019, 19:31", "20 Jan 2019, 16:16", "20 Jan 2019, 16:16", 
        "20 Jan 2019, 14:03", "20 Jan 2019, 13:58", "20 Jan 2019, 11:49", 
        "20 Jan 2019, 11:45", "20 Jan 2019, 11:39", "20 Jan 2019, 11:35"
        )), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame"), artist = structure(list(
        mbid = c("2a141b9a-d109-4f4d-8085-781e7b194bca", "", 
        "e4098450-8838-4f9e-8a91-b1ccbf99b427", "", "2a141b9a-d109-4f4d-8085-781e7b194bca", 
        "2a141b9a-d109-4f4d-8085-781e7b194bca", "2a141b9a-d109-4f4d-8085-781e7b194bca", 
        "2a141b9a-d109-4f4d-8085-781e7b194bca", "2a141b9a-d109-4f4d-8085-781e7b194bca", 
        "2a141b9a-d109-4f4d-8085-781e7b194bca", "2a141b9a-d109-4f4d-8085-781e7b194bca", 
        "2a141b9a-d109-4f4d-8085-781e7b194bca", "2a141b9a-d109-4f4d-8085-781e7b194bca", 
        "2a141b9a-d109-4f4d-8085-781e7b194bca", "2a141b9a-d109-4f4d-8085-781e7b194bca", 
        "2a141b9a-d109-4f4d-8085-781e7b194bca", "2a141b9a-d109-4f4d-8085-781e7b194bca", 
        "2a141b9a-d109-4f4d-8085-781e7b194bca", "70248960-cb53-4ea4-943a-edb18f7d336f", 
        "70248960-cb53-4ea4-943a-edb18f7d336f"), `#text` = c("Lene Marlin", 
        "Hver Gang Vi Møtes", "D.D.E.", "The Corrs", "Lene Marlin", 
        "Lene Marlin", "Lene Marlin", "Lene Marlin", "Lene Marlin", 
        "Lene Marlin", "Lene Marlin", "Lene Marlin", "Lene Marlin", 
        "Lene Marlin", "Lene Marlin", "Lene Marlin", "Lene Marlin", 
        "Lene Marlin", "Bruce Springsteen", "Bruce Springsteen"
        )), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame"), album = structure(list(
        mbid = c("3e0c3d27-ff51-41d4-bb42-e96a2eb1d950", "", 
        "1a131a36-1fd4-4a3a-b673-0f6e79d02c31", "f9964148-b49a-4567-83e2-8e27d3a069f7", 
        "6c293557-1a20-4cf6-80e8-5bb7d7ab4e55", "", "", "", "", 
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "020fb1b8-246f-3767-9736-db6bb552e729", 
        "020fb1b8-246f-3767-9736-db6bb552e729"), `#text` = c("Lost in a Moment", 
        "Hver gang vi møtes (Sesong 7)", "Jippi", "VH1 Presents The Corrs Live in Dublin", 
        "Another Day", "Here We Are - Historier så langt", "Here We Are - Historier så langt", 
        "Here We Are - Historier så langt", "Here We Are - Historier så langt", 
        "Here We Are - Historier så langt", "Here We Are - Historier så langt", 
        "Here We Are - Historier så langt", "Here We Are - Historier så langt", 
        "Here We Are - Historier så langt", "Here We Are - Historier så langt", 
        "Here We Are - Historier så langt", "Here We Are - Historier så langt", 
        "Here We Are - Historier så langt", "Born in the U.S.A.", 
        "Born in the U.S.A.")), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")), row.names = c(NA, 
    20L), class = "data.frame"))
```

Using

```
dat <- lapply(dat, rbind)
```

Does not actually change the structure in anyway. I think this is because 3 of the columns in each dataframe are actually `list`'s/`dataframe`'s in their own right. How can I promote these dataframe columns to just regular character columns so they can be bound together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider `cbind` on all those elements since they share same number of observation top level list:

```
new_dat_list <- lapply(dat_list, function(x) do.call(cbind, x))

new_dat_list
```